# Make automatic termination proof use different size function

Tags: isabelle, termination

I have written a custom size function `size2` for my datatype. Using this function I can manually prove the termination of my function:

```
termination 
apply (relation "measure (λ(a,b,c). size2 c)")
apply auto
done
```

Is there a way to make `fun` use my alternative size function for the automatic termination proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function `f` can be registered as a measure function for the termination prover by declaring the lemma `is_measure f` with the attribute `measure_function`. In your case, this looks as follows.

```
lemma is_measure_size2 [measure_function]: "is_measure size2" ..
```

Then, `lexicographic_order`, which `fun` uses, and `size_change` try `size2`, too.