# Termination checking for product types

Tags: tuples, isabelle, termination

The following function definition is accepted by Isabelle, so the termination checker is happy with it:

```
datatype 'a List = N | C 'a "'a List"

fun dequeue' :: "'a List × 'a List ⇒ ('a option × 'a queue)" where
  "dequeue' (N, N) = (None, AQueue N N)"
 |"dequeue' (xs, C y ys) = (Some y, AQueue xs ys)"
 |"dequeue' (xs, N) = dequeue' (N, reverse xs)"
```

This seemingly equivalent definition, using a custom, but isomorphic data type instead of a pair, is rejected:

```
fun dequeue :: "'a queue ⇒ ('a option × 'a queue)" where
  "dequeue (AQueue N N) = (None, AQueue N N)"
 |"dequeue (AQueue xs (C y ys)) = (Some y, AQueue xs ys)"
 |"dequeue (AQueue xs N) = dequeue (AQueue N (reverse xs))"
```

Why is that? Is there some special setup for pairs here, and if so, can I extend that setup to my custom data type? Should maybe `datatype` do that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to answer that myself. After digging through some code, I found this in `HOL/Fun_Def.thy`:

```
lemma measure_fst[measure_function]: "is_measure f ⟹ is_measure (λp. f (fst p))"
by (rule is_measure_trivial)
lemma measure_snd[measure_function]: "is_measure f ⟹ is_measure (λp. f (snd p))"
by (rule is_measure_trivial)
```

and indeed by duplicating that setup using

```
datatype 'a queue = AQueue (young: "'a List") (old: "'a List")

lemma [measure_function]: "is_measure f ⟹ is_measure (f ∘ young)" ..
```

The second function definition in the code above goes through as well.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534558/make-automatic-termination-proof-use-different-size-function?rq=1

Comment: It also works to write `lemma [measure_function]: "is_measure f ⟹ is_measure (λ q. f (young q, old y))"`, which should be relatively complete. I wonder if that should be the default.