# Proving termination of Takeuchi function in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, termination

Here is my try at proving that [Takeuchi function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9301113.pdf) does [terminate](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019079900632):

```
function moore :: "(int ⇒ int ⇒ int) ⇒ (int ⇒ int ⇒ int)" where
"moore x y z = ((if (x ≤ y) then 0  else 1) (max(x,y,z) - min(x,y,z)) (x - min(x,y,z)))"


fun tk :: "int ⇒ int ⇒ int ⇒ int" where
"tk x y z = ( if x ≤ y then y else tk (tk (x-1) y z) (tk (y-1) z x) (tk (z-1) x y) )"
```

there are several problems here. First I should return a triple in the function moore. Right now, the system is complaining with error:

> Type unification failed: Clash of types "int" and "_ ⇒ _"
>
> Type error in application: incompatible operand type
>
> Operator:  op ≤ x :: (int ⇒ int ⇒ int) ⇒ bool Operand:   y :: int

Then, of course the termination proof does not succeed since I didn't apply the termination function above (the way to this should be similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534558/make-automatic-termination-proof-use-different-size-function)).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `moore` function currently does not return a triple but a function taking two `int`s and returning an `int`. For a triple, you would have to write `int × int × int`. Also, tuples are constructed as `(x, y, z)`, not as `x y z` like you did.

Also, there is no reason to use `fun` (let alone `function`) to define the `moore` function, since it is not recursive. `definition` works fine. For `tk`, on the other hand, you will need to use `function` since there is no obvious lexicographic termination measure.

Also, functions returning triple are usually a bit ugly to handle in Isabelle; it makes more sense to define three individual functions. Putting all this together, you can then define your functions like this:

```
definition m1 where "m1 = (λ(x,y,z). if x ≤ y then 0 else 1)"
definition m2 where "m2 = (λ(x,y,z). nat (Max {x, y, z} - Min {x, y, z}))"
definition m3 where "m3 = (λ(x,y,z). nat (x - Min {x, y, z}))"

function tk :: "int ⇒ int ⇒ int ⇒ int" where
  "tk x y z = ( if x ≤ y then y else tk (tk (x-1) y z) (tk (y-1) z x) (tk (z-1) x y))"
  by auto
```

You can then easily prove a partial correctness theorem for the `tk` function using the partial induction rule `tk.pinduct`:

```
lemma tk_altdef:
  assumes "tk_dom (x, y, z)"
  shows   "tk x y z = (if x ≤ y then y else if y ≤ z then z else x)"
  using assms by (induction rule: tk.pinduct) (simp_all add: tk.psimps)
```

The `tk_dom (x, y, z)` assumption says that `tk` terminates on the values `(x, y, z)`.

Now, if I read the paper you linked correctly, the template for the termination proof looks like this:

```
termination proof (relation "m1 <*mlex*> m2 <*mlex*> m3 <*mlex*> {}", goal_cases)
  case 1
  show "wf (m1 <*mlex*> m2 <*mlex*> m3 <*mlex*> {})"
    by (auto intro: wf_mlex)
next
  case (2 x y z)
  thus ?case sorry
next
  case (3 x y z)
  thus ?case sorry
next
  case (4 x y z)
  thus ?case sorry
next
  case (5 x y z)
  thus ?case sorry
qed
```

In the last four cases here, you will have to do the actual work of showing that the measure decreases. The `<*mlex*>` operator combines several measures into a single lexicographic measure. The relevant rules for showing that something is in contained in that measure are `mlex_less` and `mlex_le`.

Comment: thank you, @ManuelEberl. Is there any Isabelle tutorial related to proving termination of programs?

Comment: There is the function package manual, which is linked on the Isabelle website: http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2017/doc/functions.pdf

Comment: Also, you may consider this nitpicking, but what we are talking about here is termination of *recursive function specifications*, not termination of *programs*. HOL is a logical framework; it does not have any concept of a program and execution. All it knows is functions.